# Why are third party apps entirely excluded from USB OTG since Android 7?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, file-management

Android KitKat rendered SD cards next to useless for writing, but did not affect USB-OTG at all.

Android 6.0 put USB OTG into read-only, which can be a good thing, but sometimes, I want to write to OTG.

Android 7.0 entirely hides OTG from anything else than Google built-in Stock File Manager,  **which is not even nearly as good and functional as ES File Explorer *from 2012.*** (yes, 2012. No typo here.)

Is that for security reasons?  But what if I actually want read/write OTG access?

What's next? Removing Internet access for security reasons?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access media files on NTFS formatted USB OTG drive (preferably without rooting)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135439/access-media-files-on-ntfs-formatted-usb-otg-drive-preferably-without-rooting)

Answer (score 1):

Though my phone could have Android 7, I've stuck with 6 because of compatibility with a few Xposed modules so I don't know if this helps you, but a file manager named [MiXplorer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1523691) has it's own OTG driver, so *maybe* it could r/w your OTG device. By default this is disabled, you need to turn it on in the settings.

Please let me know if it did work for you

Comment: You kept Android 6? Understandable.

Comment: I'm planning to upgrade to 7, but no further. From 8 there are a lot of restrictions (which I could overcome with root what I always have, but what if something goes wrong and need to debug and fix on the go), and also that new "Material" 2 design with that more aggressive white design and bunch of curly corners...
I'm planning getting a new phone, but I'm afraid I'll not find a suitable one with 7 :/

Comment: The custom On-The-Go (OTG) driver of MiXplorer supports: FAT32 (read/write), exFat (read/write) and NTFS (read only). [**Here**](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205029/51773) is explained how to enable MiXplorer's OTG.